# Installing ext-grpc to allow an update in google/cloud-firestore

Tags: php, google-cloud-firestore, composer-php, grpc

I'm trying to install google-firestore with composer but it just installs the oldest version of it "package is fixed to v0.1.0 (lock file version)". The problem is that google/cloud-firestore requires ext-grpc. I need help installing this extension in my system. I tried composer grcp/grpc but got this message:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

> Problem 1
> - Root composer.json requires google/cloud-firestore ^1.0 || ^2.0, found google/cloud-firestore[v1.0.0, ..., v1.28.0] but the package is fixed to v0.1.0 (lock file version) by a partial update and that version does not match. Make sure you list it as an argument for the update command.

> Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.
> You can also try re-running composer require with an explicit version constraint, e.g. "composer require grpc/grpc:*" to figure out if any version is installable, or "composer require grpc/grpc:^2.1" if you know which you need.

> Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json and ./composer.lock to their original content.

I'm using composer 2.4.4. My json file is:

```
"require": {
    "twig/twig": "^3.5",
    "twbs/bootstrap": "^5.2",
    "google/cloud-core": "^1.49",
    "google/cloud-firestore": "^1.28.0"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "Vpmo\\":"src/classes/"
    }
}
```

I tried to install composer package require google/cloud-firestore. I received this message:

> Cannot use google/cloud-firestore's latest version v1.28.0 as it requires ext-grpc * which is missing from your
> platform.

Using version ^0.1.0 for google/cloud-firestore

Then I tried the command: `composer update`
I received this message:

> Loading composer repositories with package information
> Updating dependencies
> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

> Problem 1
> - Root composer.json requires google/cloud-firestore ^1.28.0 -> satisfiable by google/cloud-firestore[v1.28.0].
> - google/cloud-firestore v1.28.0 requires ext-grpc * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's grpc extension.

> To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:

I didn't lock it! When I downloaded it for the first time it already came with this attribute

Comment: And your question is? And please [edit] in the exact command line you entered to provoke this message together with the composer.json project configuration file and share the composer version. And an additional question: Why do you lock a version you deem too low in the first place? Was that by accident? What prevents you to recover from the accident if it was one? Which of the suggestions in the message you already share in your question have you tried and/or what prevents you from trying them?

Comment: im using composer 2.4.4. My json file is:     "require": {
        "twig/twig": "^3.5",
        "twbs/bootstrap": "^5.2",
        "google/cloud-core": "^1.49",
        "google/cloud-firestore": "^1.28.0"
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Vpmo\\":"src/classes/"
        }
    }
I tried to install composer package require google/cloud-firestore. I received this message:
Cannot use google/cloud-firestore's latest version v1.28.0 as it requires ext-grpc * which is missing from your
platform.
Using version ^0.1.0 for google/cloud-firestor
Trying

Comment: Then I tried the command: composer update
I received this message:
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires google/cloud-firestore ^1.28.0 -> satisfiable by google/cloud-firestore[v1.28.0].
    - google/cloud-firestore v1.28.0 requires ext-grpc * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's grpc extension.

To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:

Comment: please [edit] and add all the details (into the question).

Comment: I didnt lock it ! When I downloaded it for the first time it already came with this attribute

Comment: what parts of `it requires ext-grpc * which is missing from your platform.`  / `it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's grpc extension. To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files` are an issue/unclear for you?

Comment: i´ve downloaded file grpc-1.41.0.tgz from https://pecl.php.net/package/grpc.
I unzipped it but I'm having doubts about how to install it

Comment: more straight forward docs are here: https://cloud.google.com/php/grpc#using-pecl - install the dependencies and then the extension .

Comment: @Jeferson, did the previous comment address your concern? If so, please post it as an answer in order for other community members to find this helpful.